# One WooCommerce AJAX call always timing out after 5 seconds

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have WP with WooCommerce installed, and it’s been working great for a couple of years. In the last little while (month? – not quite sure when this started), the WooCommerce cart widget has not been updating when a customer adds a product to their cart.

This can be seen on the following page (https://adventuretaco.com/product/tacoma-to-tundra-hard-brake-line-kit/) by

1. Open browser developer tools and switch to the Networking tab
2. Click the Add to Cart button
   Edit/update: ==> Page reloads as expected
3. Watch the “cart” widget on the right and note that it does not update
4. As the page is reloading and loading all resources, watch the browser dev tools, and look for the request to https://adventuretaco.com/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments
5. The result is that it is always cut off after *exactly* 5 seconds. (or 5.01/5.02 seconds).

REPRO 2:

1. Open browser developer tools and switch to the Networking tab
2. browse to https://adventuretaco.com/minimal
3. watch the browser dev tools, and look for the request to https://adventuretaco.com/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments

Because the response doesn’t come back in that time, the cart never updates. However, direct requests (non-AJAX) to that URL do return correctly (after more than 5 seconds) with the correct cart data.

Why is this request getting cut off? The answer might be in the browser dev tool data, but I don’t see it (or know what I’m looking for).

The backend is linux/nginx.

Comment: The ajax request gets cancelled (note, not timed out!) because your entire page gets refreshed and reloaded from the server. So somewhere you're not preventing a default form submission when the Add to Cart button is pressed (notice in the Network too, the first request after the button press is a non-XHR request to tacoma-to-tundra-hard-brake-line-kit/, followed by a whole pile of reuqests to reload the rest of the site's assets, just like when the page was originally loaded).

Comment: Provide a [mre] of the issue here in the question if you want to get a formal answer. (see also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [ask]). But essentially you probably need to use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the right place in the JS code.

Comment: This thread can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76495561/woocommerce-mini-cart-is-coming-blank-on-add-to-cart-from-product-page

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, the clarification of cancelled/timed out is a good one. Note however that the entire page being refreshed is expected, and it is *when the page reloads after the refresh,* that the AJAX call is cancelled after 5 seconds. Or, are you saying that the cancelled call is one from *before* the refresh, that then shows up in the network trace *after* the refresh as other resources are being loaded?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - thanks, but I'm using a theme that does not disable the cart fragments, and it is the exact call that is shown in the other thread that is being cancelled/not completing for me.

Comment: @ADyson - I've created a page that is a minimal repro. I can't paste the code here, as this is happening as part of the Wordpress "flow" but this page has essentially no content on it except for the WooCommerce Mini-Cart.

Simply loading the page with the Network tab of browser dev tools up shows the behavior I mentioned. There's no need to click a button/submit a form/etc. The request is - for some reason - cancelled after 5 seconds.

https://adventuretaco.com/minimal/

Comment: That `?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments` is known to cause performance issues, https://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-with-woocommerce-wc-ajaxget_refreshed_fragments/ Do you have any "performance enhacing" plugins in use? One of those might perhaps deliberately set a low timeout for this AJAX request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I don't have a "real" answer to this, but in case others have the same issue and stumble on this question that I asked, my solution was not what I expected, but more than I hoped for.

I moved from Azure (where I was running Wordpress on Linux with Flexible MySQL) to AWS (where I'm running a Lightsail WP instance and a Lightsail MySQL database).

Cost is about the same per month - as of this answer, in the $20 range - but holy smokes is the AWS platform *so* much more performant.

Not just this call for the WC cart, but everything on my site is orders of magnitude faster. Almost feels like I don't need a caching plugin, though I continue to use one as it's clearly good practice.

Migration was easy as well - just used MySql Workbench to copy over the database, and then FTP to grab the wp-content directory. Was up and running in less than a few hours, and it was a simple DNS change to point the domain to the new IPs.

Hope this helps anyone else considering perf on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the comments on the first question, the cancellation doesn't timeout, it get's cancelled, which means, that we can safely assume, that it happens on the client-side.

So I searched for somewhere this timeout is set on the client side, and as of woocommerce 8.3.0, in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php` you have a method called `get_script_data($handle)`, which includes a case for `wc-cart-fragments`:

```php
case 'wc-cart-fragments':
    $params = array(
        'ajax_url'        => WC()->ajax_url(),
        'wc_ajax_url'     => WC_AJAX::get_endpoint('%%endpoint%%'),
        'cart_hash_key'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_hash_key', 'wc_cart_hash_' . md5(get_current_blog_id() . '_' . get_site_url(get_current_blog_id(), '/') . get_template())),
        'fragment_name'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_fragment_name', 'wc_fragments_' . md5(get_current_blog_id() . '_' . get_site_url(get_current_blog_id(), '/') . get_template())),
        'request_timeout' => 5000,
    );
    break;
```

Which has `'request_timeout' => 5000,`

Be aware that this is probably a performance parameter set by woocommerce intentionally, so the best solution is still to fix your site's responsiveness. However, if you want to change it, I have two suggestions:

1. Since I only experience this during development, I have just modified the file directly on my local wordpress instance. In this case I won't accidentally push the code to production.
2. If you actually need to change this timeout setting, you should do it through a filter instead. In the end of the above method, you have a line `return apply_filters('woocommerce_get_script_data', $params, $handle);`, so you can add a filter like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_script_data', 'custom_woocommerce_get_script_data', 10, 2);
function custom_woocommerce_get_script_data($params, $handle)
{
    if ($handle === 'wc-cart-fragments') {
        $params['request_timeout'] = 10000;
    }
    return $params;
}
```