# WooCommerce 'Add to Cart' stopped working - wc_cart_fragments_params is not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I've built a site for a friend using WordPress, WooCommerce and the Werkstatt theme.

All was going well until a recent automatic update. Now the 'Add to Cart' button doesn't work on the product pages. Obviously this has been a big problem as my friend can no longer sell on the site and has had to remove the shop section until it's fixed.

Fixes I've tried so far:

- Disabling plugins one by one
- Disabling the 'WooCommerce' folder of the active theme
- Several suggestions from SO regarding when/where jQuery is called
- Updating all scripts/plugins

> Uncaught ReferenceError: wc_cart_fragments_params is not defined
> init https://thisisrobfenton.com/wp-content/themes/werkstatt/assets/js/app.min.js?ver=4.7.4:1
> jQuery 2
> dispatch
> handle
>
> `Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: https://thisisrobfenton.com/wp-content/themes/werkstatt/assets/js/vendor/typed.min.js?ver=4.7.4 Source Map URL: typed.min.js.map`

I'm okay with WordPress, CSS and some PHP. I'm not a JavaScript coder unfortunately.

What can I try next?

Fixes I've tried so far:

- Disabling plugins one by one
- Disabling the 'WooCommerce' folder of the active theme
- Several suggestions from SO regarding when/where jQuery is called
- Updating all scripts/plugins

> Uncaught ReferenceError: wc_cart_fragments_params is not defined
> init https://thisisrobfenton.com/wp-content/themes/werkstatt/assets/js/app.min.js?ver=4.7.4:1
> jQuery 2
> dispatch
> handle
>
> `Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: https://thisisrobfenton.com/wp-content/themes/werkstatt/assets/js/vendor/typed.min.js?ver=4.7.4 Source Map URL: typed.min.js.map`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76505287/3730754

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you SO much! I've been searching for days and hadn't seen that thread. It's worked instantly and saved me so much trouble. I really appreciate your comment, thank you!

Comment: I added that in the search: `[woocommerce] fragments`… then hit the tab "newest"… It was the 3rd thread: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bwoocommerce%5d%20fragments&searchOn=3